# AWS Transcribe client does not provide an export named 'transcribeClient'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js, amazon-transcribe

I'm trying to integrate AWS Transcribe in my Node.JS application. AWS S3 and Polly works fine, but AWS Transcribe does not. I'm using the example code of AWS.

When I want to start a transcribe job by the [AWS example code](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javascriptv3/example_code/transcribe/src/transcribe_create_job.js) I receive the **following error**: The requested module './libs/transcribeClient.js' does not provide an export named 'transcribeClient'

That was also the only file where I received the error that required is not defined. I wonder why it only happens with AWS transcribe but not with the other services as well? I'm also able to start a transcribe job via the AWS CLI.

**That AWS Transcribe code does not work - transcribeClient.js:**

```
const AWS_BUCKET_NAME="X"
const AWS_REGION="eu-central-1"
const AWS_ACCESS_KEY="XXX"
const AWS_SECRET_KEY="XXX"

// snippet-start:[transcribe.JavaScript.createclientv3]
const { TranscribeClient } = require('@aws-sdk/client-transcribe');
// Create anAmazon EC2 service client object.
const transcribeClient = new TranscribeClient({ AWS_REGION, AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY });
module.exports = { transcribeClient };
```

**That AWS Polly code works - pollyClient.js:**

```
const AWS_BUCKET_NAME="X"
const AWS_REGION="eu-central-1"
const AWS_ACCESS_KEY="XXX"
const AWS_SECRET_KEY="XXX"

// snippet-start:[polly.JavaScript.createclientv3]
const { PollyClient } =require( "@aws-sdk/client-polly");
// Create an Amazon S3 service client object.
const pollyClient = new PollyClient({ AWS_REGION, AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY});
module.exports = { pollyClient };
```

I'm looking forward to reading from you! Thanks!

Comment: Install `"@aws-sdk/client-transcribe": "^3.3.0",`

Comment: Thanks! I installed it again, but it's still not working. When I replace `module.exports` with `export { transcribeClient };` I get `const { TranscribeClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-transcribe"); ReferenceError: require is not defined` and if I don't replace it, I still receive: ` The requested module './libs/transcribeClient.js' does not provide an export named 'transcribeClient'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Now it's working with my Node.js 12 environment.

**package.json**
I changed `"type": "modules"` to `"type": "commonjs"`.

**transcribeClient.js needs to look like this:**
Here I changed export to module.exports.

```
const { TranscribeClient } = require("@aws-sdk/client-transcribe");
const transcribeClient = new TranscribeClient({ AWS_REGION, AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY});
module.exports = { transcribeClient };
```

**transcribe_create_job.js needs to look like this:**
Here I changed the import statement to require.

```
const { StartTranscriptionJobCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-transcribe");
const { transcribeClient } = require("./libs/transcribeClient.js")

// Set the parameters
const params = {
  TranscriptionJobName: "test123",
  LanguageCode: "en-GB", // For example, 'en-US'
  MediaFormat: "webm", // For example, 'wav'
  Media: {
    MediaFileUri: "https://x.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dlpasiddi.webm",
  },
};

const run = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await transcribeClient.send(
      new StartTranscriptionJobCommand(params)
    );
    console.log("Success - put", data);
    return data; // For unit tests.
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  }
};
run();
```